# File not found error when playing a copied resource using AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am using a sequence of three functions to play a video using AVPlayerViewController on iOS :

1. first I add the video files to my project by copying them to my project root folder and then drag and drop them in xcode project root
2. First Function that copies the file to the application's document folder :

   a. Get the document path

   ```
   class func getPath(fileName: String) -> String{

    let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    return fileURL.path!

   }
   ```

   b. COPY THE FILE

   ```
   class func copyFile(fileName: NSString) {

    let dbPath: String = getPath(fileName as String)
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath) {

       let documentsURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL
       print(documentsURL)
       let fromPath = documentsURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName as String)

       var error : NSError?
       do {
           try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(fromPath.path!, toPath: dbPath)
       } catch let error1 as NSError {
           print(error1.localizedDescription)
       }
    }
   }
   ```
3. In my app delegate application(...) function I call Util.copyFile("EVGS_VID1.MOV")
4. in a view controller I have a function playVideo(fileName:String) :

   ```
   func playVideo(fileName:String){

     let videoPath:String = Util.getPath(fileName) 
     var fileSize : UInt64 = 0
     //Check if file exists
     do {
       let attr : NSDictionary? = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(videoPath)

       if let _attr = attr {
           fileSize = _attr.fileSize();
       }
     } catch {
       print("Error: \(error)")
     }

     let playerViewController:AVPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
     var url:NSURL =  NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath,isDirectory: false)
     let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
     playerViewController.player = player

     self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
       playerViewController.player!.play()
     }  
   }
   ```

but when I call the playVideo in my view controller it shows the player with no video and I got an exception :

> `Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “EVGS_VID1.mov” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/61169756-1DCE-49B1-99F4-27854DDF4929/Documents/EVGS_VID1.mov, NSUnderlyingError=0x1572bbbf0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}`

I am using the same functions copyFile and getPath to copy SQLite database and it's working

Comment: Allan, the message is clear. The file you think you creating isn't there. Try adding "Application support iTunes file sharing", setting it to YES to your info.plist and you can check for yourself and even add the file manually so that you can get around this error and move forward.

Comment: check if the file is copied in your document directory, may be you have some problem with the file name you are using/storing

Comment: Please check if the path of `let dbPath: String = getPath(fileName as String)` and  `let videoPath:String = Util.getPath(fileName)` are same